# Помогите понять алгоритм ( задача с js найти подстроку полиндрома)

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Я только напишу часть кода, на которой я собственно застрял.
Функция expCent будет возвращать максимальную длину, на которую нам удалось сдвинуться по условиям
Вопрос, как у нас передается в функции expandFromCenter наша середина(макс.длинна), если у нас итерируется одни и те же элементы , так как мы передаем их через i . то есть  L=0, R=0 и так далее. , почему к примеру в слове "babad" начинает while Отрабатывать именно на середине , если у нас и  до середины элементы получается одинаковые a=a ..
Вообщем не пойму, как нашлась длинна по условиям while (

```
const palin2 = function(s) {

for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {                           
    let len1 = expCent(s,i,i)

function expCent(s,L,R) {
    while (L >= 0 && R < s.length && s[L] === s[R]) {
    console.log(`левый - ${s[L]}, ${L} правый - ${s[R]}, ${R}`)
    L--
    R++
  }
  return R - L - 1
}
}
}

console.log(palin2('babad'))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция expandFromCenter выполняет цикл while до тех пор, пока условия L >= 0 && R < s.length && s[L] === s[R] соблюдаются. Каждую итерацию цикла значение L уменьшается на 1, а значение R увеличивается на 1. Это означает, что функция сдвигается в обе стороны от центра (заданной через аргументы L и R).

Как только одно из условий станет невыполнимым, цикл завершится. Например, если L < 0, то функция достигла начала строки, и цикл завершится. Если R >= s.length, то функция достигла конца строки, и цикл также завершится. Если s[L] !== s[R], то цикл также завершится, так как символы не совпадают.

Каждую итерацию цикла функция сравнивает символы строки с помощью s[L] === s[R]. Если символы совпадают, то цикл продолжается, иначе цикл завершается

В следующей итерации цикла while символы s[-1] и s[5] сравниваются. Так как индекс -1 выходит за пределы строки, условие цикла while перестает соблюдаться, и цикл завершается.

Функция expandFromCenter возвращает разницу между R и L минус 1, то есть длину самого длинного палиндрома, найденного в цикле while. Это значение записывается в переменную len1.

Ваш код содержит еще один цикл for, который итерируется от 0 до s.length. Внутри этого цикла вызывается функция expandFromCenter с аргументами L и R, равными i и i+1 соответственно. Это означает, что функция expandFromCenter вызывается для каждой пары соседних символов в строке. Она находит самый длинный палиндром, начинающийся с этой пары соседних символов.

Comment: Мне вот непонятен момент, у нас идет первая итерация, передается в функию строка и координаты R=0,L=0 для строки babad . значит R: b=0, и L: b=0 , по циклу while условия соблюдены , делаем вторую итерацию : L-- это уже -1 и мы выходим из цикла, и делаем return R - L - 1 . то есть 0-0-1 . и в переменную len записывается -1 ? . в консоли просто выводится не так как я считаю в уме

Comment: Вы правильно описали процесс выполнения цикла while в первой итерации. Однако, в следующих итерациях цикла while переменные L и R также изменяются. После первой итерации цикла while переменные L и R станут равными -1 и 1 соответственно. Во второй итерации цикла while переменные L и R станут равными -2 и 2 соответственно. И так далее, пока условие цикла while соблюдается.

В вашем коде условие цикла while соблюдается, пока L >= 0 && R < s.length && s[L] === s[R]. Это означает, что цикл будет продолжаться, пока индекс L не выйдет за пределы строки (то есть L >= 0)

Comment: Индекс R также не должен выйти за пределы строки (то есть R < s.length), и символы s[L] и s[R] должны быть равны (то есть s[L] === s[R]). Как только одно из этих условий не соблюдается, цикл завершается.

Comment: Поэтому, когда вызывается функция expandFromCenter со значением i равным 2 (например, в строке 'babad'), то аргументы L и R равны 2. Функция сравнивает символы s[2] и s[2], которые равны 'b' и 'b' соответственно, условие цикла while соблюдается, и цикл продолжается. В следующей итерации цикла while символы s[1] и s[3] сравниваются, цикл продолжается. В следующей итерации цикла while символы s[0] и s[4] сравниваются, цикл продолжается. В следующей итерации цикла while символы s[-1] и s[5] сравниваются.

Comment: Индекс -1 выходит за пределы строки, условие цикла while перестает соблюдаться, и цикл завершается. Функция expandFromCenter возвращает разницу между R и L минус 1, то есть 5 - (-1) - 1, что равно 7.

Это значение записывается в переменную len2, которая сравнивается с переменной len1 с помощью оператора Math.max. Значение, которое больше, сохраняется в переменную maxLen. После этого цикл for продолжается со следующей итерацией.

Comment: Как только все итерации цикла for будут завершены, функция palin2 возвращает значение переменной maxLen. Это значение соответствует длине самого длинного палиндрома, найденного в строке s.